# iPhone 5 device and simulator differences

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-5

Im developing an app that should work on iOS 4 and above, i just tested the app for the (ios6 iPhone5) on the simulator, because im in Jordan, Middle East; and iPhone5 didnt arrive to our country, dose the simulator work just like the actual device??

by the way when i test my app for the iPhone 5 i use the iphone simulator 6.0, retina 4.0.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Can i just upload my app to the itunesConnect without running it on actual device??

Comment: I've had no issues with it as of yet, all seems to be fine although the simulator is never exactly the same as the actual device no matter what the target (iPhone 4, etc.)

Comment: Always test your app in Device itself, you ca do it after you finish it. We cant assure simulator to be completely correct

Answer (score 0):

I also test my app for iPhone5 using iPhone simulator just like you. Some other experienced developers around me tell me that it is ok.

Comment: Can i just upload my app to the itunesConnect without running it on actual device??

Comment: we have just submitted an app to the itunesConnect without testing on actual  iPhone5 device. BTW, the app is waiting for review now. So, you can also try it. Good luck!

Comment: Take into account that iPhone5 has armv7s architecture which is not the same as the armv7 that iPhone4 uses. There could be differences that can make the app crash in iPhone5 but not in iPhone4. Simulator runs in i386 architecture and can not catch those differences.